# WPF CheckBox is not squared

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox

I have a strange bug here. `CheckBox` controls has always been squared. Now I've noticed that it's not. It's one pixel wider than tall. After experimenting a bit with empty WPF applications, I've discovered that it depends on the `UseLayoutRounding` setting. If it's set to `false`, the CheckBox is never a square. If it's set to `true`, it depends on the actual layout values and how they are rounded, or snapped to pixels.

Just create an empty WPF application targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2, 4.6 or 4.6.1 (I've tested these) and run it on Windows 10. Here's the minimal XAML to reproduce. The third state shows another filled "square" box that makes it easier to recognise the form without measuring pixels.

```
<Window
    x:Class="CheckBoxTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" UseLayoutRounding="False">
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="{x:Null}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then drag the window's width and watch the CheckBox as it toggles between square and one pixel wider. In another of my applications it's always one pixel wider and never has a squared form.

Is that a bug in WPF? Does it only happen on Windows 10?

PS: Better not use a high DPI monitor for this, it may be harder to see there.

Comment: It's all vector with WPF, so it's being worked out as a prelapsarian floating point abstraction and then mapped onto pixels. I wouldn't call it a "bug", more of a regrettable byproduct of the human condition.

Comment: Dont get me wrong, but what is the purpose of this question? Its a bit flickering on resizing the Window, but its also flickering here without setting `UseLayoutRounding` to false

Comment: @lokusking The CheckBox isn't squared. It's distorted and ugly. I'd like to fix that in my application.

Comment: **To the downvoters, again:** Am I really the only person on this planet that cares about a pixel-perfect GUI design? Is it that bad already? Or are those guys elsewhere and developers don't make GUIs?

Comment: This question is probably better off being directed to WPF. It's kind of hard for the average SO user to tell wether this is a bug or not and if it **is** a bug what would you expect us to do about it?

Answer (score 2):

Its a bug in the default style of the checkbox.  For some reason they decided to not use layout rounding on the grid in the checkbox control template.

```
                    <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <Grid x:Name="markGrid" UseLayoutRounding="True">
                            <Path x:Name="optionMark" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z " Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="1" Opacity="0" Stretch="None"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark" Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="2" Opacity="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
```

Maybe because even if you modify the template like this, it still inchworms when you resize it in the designer, but not when you run it.